# Taking RGB image of (256*256) size of any location using Google Earth Engine API

Tags: google-earth-engine-python-api, google-colab

All the bands in the GeoTiff file only contain NA values. Below is my code.
I first started with getting an image from ImageCollection and choosing the bands which I want i.e.RGB and export to drive as GeoTiff file.

```
col1 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA').first().select(['B2','B3','B4'])

coords = geo_file['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates']
aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(coords)

task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(**{
    'image': col1,
    'description': 'new_old',
    'folder': 'DS1 Project',
    'scale': 100,
    'fileFormat': 'GeoTIFF',
    'region': coords,
    'crs':'EPSG:4326'
})
task.start()
```

Then I opened the geotiff image using raster and checking the values:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show
fp = r'/content/new_old.tif'
img = rasterio.open(fp)
print(img.read(1))
```

> array([[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan],
> [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan],

Can you figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: And what do you have in 'coordinates'?

Comment: Coordinates are the vertex points of a random rectangular region in terms of lat and long.

Answer (score 0):

If the polygon coordinates (`coords`) are not within the footprint of the first image in the image collection (`ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA').first()`), the exported GeoTiff will contain no data.